# How to setup a virtual Ubuntu machine (20.04) for external network connection?

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, virtualbox-networking, multipass

I'm trying to setup two virtual machines (both running Ubuntu 20.04 server) on a physical server running Ubuntu 20.04 as well. Both VMs have to be reachable for external network connections via the internet.
I've tried Multipass, but it doesn't support network bridging. I've tried MAAS but it requires two physical NICs (which I don't have).
Is there any other method?

I've now changed my setup and I'm using VirtualBox which allows network bridging.
Thanks for the help - it was indeed a missing feature on Multipass as fast and easy as it is otherwise.

Comment: The three common VM Host applications (QEMU, VirtualBox, VMWare) all support bridging. The method depends upon your VM Host application, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1298484/edit) to specify which host application you are using. FYI: Multipass is currently [testing bridging](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/118#issuecomment-734426114) using a VirtualBox backend.

Comment: Another way for virtualisation is Proxmox. And bridging is included in linux kernel. Go for Ubuntu 20.04 add network bridge in google.